How to handle browser URL navigation with Sveltekit SPA and client side routing
We have a custom server that is serving our svelte app on a single URL endpoint. This svelte app is made to be an SPA. Our app has a few pages you can visit, making use of the client side routing for navigating the pages such that the URL would also change as different pages are navigated to.
What i cant seem to find, is any information on how you are supposed to handle URL changes in the browser such as a refresh or navigating to another page. Naturally, changing the url will send it directly to the server for which we do not have a service running, we only have a single endpoint that hosts the SPA svelte app.
I would have presumed svelte has some sort of mechanism to catch URL changes and handle the request in its own internal routing mechanism but cannot find anything related. Is what i am suggesting even possible or am i missing something?
The closest i can find is this navigation subscription that triggers when the browsers url is triggered but is this how its supposed to be detected? Otherwise i can only think of using this hook to make it call the app serving endpoint instead of whatever is called but then is there no way to simply get svelte to load a certain page  instead of sending the url request? I guess this is probably for when you have server end points for your routes and not applicable in an SPA.
Any help or clarification would be appreciated.


What i cant seem to find, is any information on how you are supposed to handle URL changes in the browser such as a refresh or navigating to another page.

In these cases, the server needs to send back the app.html (or index.html file, or whatever it's called after the build). When the web browser receives this file, it will start the SPA, and client-side routing will then take care of displaying the right page based on the current URL.
How you configure the server to send back that file this depends on which server you use. For example, if you use nginx, I found a quick example:
https://github.com/johnknapp/svelte-rollup-routify-smui-spa/blob/master/nginx-spa.conf

  server_tokens off; # suppress nginx version info

  listen   8080;
  listen   [::]:8080 default ipv6only=on;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  server_name _; # all hostnames

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; # for SPA
  }
}

The main thing here related to SPAs is the try_files line. There they will send back the file matching the URL if one is found (used for the CSS files, JS files and static files (such as images)), and if no one matches, they will send back the index.html file.
EDIT
Another option is to build your SvelteKit project with the static adapter. Then for each route, you will get a corresponding .html file that can be sent back for the URL it has.


What i cant seem to find, is any information on how you are supposed to handle URL changes in the browser such as a refresh or navigating to another page.

You don't have to do anything, SvelteKit has baked in code that will intercept any navigation "to itself" and will handle loading the components and data client side for you.

Naturally, changing the url will send it directly to the server for which we do not have a service running, we only have a single endpoint that hosts the SPA svelte app.

Nope, it will not go back to the server (with the exception to load extra components and maybe data, but if you don't need those you will not even see a "hit" in your server logs.

I would have presumed svelte has some sort of mechanism to catch URL changes and handle the request in its own internal routing mechanism but cannot find anything related. Is what i am suggesting even possible or am i missing something?

Yes it has the mechanism, it is possible, but it might not be written out that explicitly.

What is important though is configuring correctly:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
export default {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            fallback: '200.html' // may differ from host to host
        })
    }
};

This will make that only a "200.html" page is built and that is the one you want to give to the user at all times (regardless of what url they initially entered to the server). How that is done depends on your host and is out of scope of SvelteKit itself. The other answer here lists for nginx, the docs have this for apache (.htaccess):
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^200\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /200.html [L]
</IfModule>

Check your server for what you need, but keep in mind to only redirect if the file was not found (otherwise you would also serve the 200 file for css, javascript, images, ...)

I think i was maybe not clear in my question. Currently the base URL to return the SPA is {ip_address:port_number}, if you click on a page it turns to {ip_address:port_number/page_name} but this isnt a valid server route. In the browsers URL bar, if you hit enter or change it, the request indeed goes to the server and return with a 404 so svelte doesnt seem to be handling this internally, thats what i was looking for, how to make svelte catch this URL change and handle it itself instead of allowing to send it to the server.

yes when you change the url and hit "enter" it goes to the server, but that is normal browser behaviour which is impossible for SvelteKit to intercept. It only works if you click links in the page itself.
To catch different urls on the server you have to implement a redirect rule as said in the second part of the answer.
I would be an extreme security issue if some javascript can intercept what you type in the address bar, just imagine that I would detect you are going to your bank website and decide to spoof it instead.

Okay, thank you for explaining, im not that experienced with client side development so didnt know that browsers make this impossible but it makes sense. Can i ask then if its possible to turn off this client side routing in svelte? Such that i no longer get /loaded_page in the URL bar? Then if the user refreshes it will just recall the root URL which will load all the files again.
